# Galaxy S10, S10+ Full Screen Mode

Tags: android, fullscreen, samsung-mobile, android-fullscreen, samsung-galaxy

How can achieve full screen mode with Samsung Galaxy S10 and S10+, the following code do not work for me:

```
getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(
// Set the content to appear under the system bars so that the
// content doesn't resize when the system bars hide and show.
SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
| View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
| View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
// Hide the nav bar and status bar
// | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
| View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
| View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY
);
```

It hide the content of the status bar but it doesn't hide the status bar it self :(

Please help

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Put in the style of your app the following fixed this issue for me:

```
<item name="android:windowLayoutInDisplayCutoutMode">shortEdges</item>
```

For more details about supporting cutout look at this:

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/display-cutout

Comment: Notice this option is only available for API level 27+, so you'll need separated themes.xml (for API level 27+ you need res/values-v27/themes.xml).
Android Studio should suggest you to do this refactor automatically and create the files for you, once you add an un-supported property to the xml.

Answer (score 1):

Try to create a style:

```
<style 
    name="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar.FullScreen" 
    parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
</style>
```

and then apply the theme to your activity:

```
<activity
   android:name=".MyActivity"
   android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar.FullScreen" 
/>
```

### UPDATE:

AFAIK, Samsung S10 has an aspect ratio of 19:9 (equivalent to 2.1)
So, in your manifest, add this tag on your `<application>`

```
<meta-data android:name="android.max_aspect" android:value="2.1" />
```

You can also try to set the resizeableActivity for Activity or Application:

```
android:resizeableActivity="true"
```

Comment: Well, try to use the same code on emulator, if it works, there's something specific to Galaxy s10, as this device will be released only June 4th there's not much I can do. If you work on Samsung, recommend to research internally.

Comment: Actually the S10, S10+ is already released and i got one. As the title of the question says, the issue is only happens on the S10, S10+.

Comment: I've edited my answer. You can try another approach.

Comment: The aspect ratio is 19:9 is 2,111111111, maybe the value should be android:value="2.2" instead. Just a guess

Comment: not worked too, i think this behavior is intended from Samsung.

Comment: You may check other apps, like Youtube, or some game, to compare the behavior.

Comment: Style items worked for me on S10e in a React Native app. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

From docs linked by Mohamad Bdour:

> Note that Android might not allow the content view to overlap the
>   system bars. To override this behavior and force content to extend
>   into the cutout area, apply any of the following flags to the view
>   visibility via the View.setSystemUiVisibility(int) method:
>
> SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
>   SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE